# PowerShell code runs considerably slower in Automation Account hybrid worker than it does directly on the hybrid worker server

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have a web scraping and HTTP posting automation written in PowerShell that I developed partially locally and partially on my hybrid worker with the authoring toolkit.
During development and testing on the hybrid worker server, it run as expected in a few hours but when the code runs on the hybrid worker from the automation account, the code is considerably slower.

There are 2 primary sections that are slowing it down in the automation account and taking around 50 seconds each, and these have to run tens of thousands of times throughout the automation:

`$unparsedJSON = ($detailsSession.Scripts)[-1].outerHTML`
There are only 31 script blocks in the $detailsSession and the script block is 806 character. This takes 0.77 millisecond on the server.

`$linkedRecord = ($linkedSession.allelements.innertext | Where-Object {$_ -like 'Record -*'})`

There are 419 elements in the $linkedSession. This line takes 13 milliseconds directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. To optimize the JSON parsing process for `$detailsSession.Scripts`, leveraging the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet is recommended over direct property access. Given that there are only 31 script blocks, each averaging around 806 characters, the parsing operation should not be
   excessively slow. By employing `ConvertFrom-Json`, the parsing process can be streamlined and potentially enhanced for improved efficiency.
2. When dealing with large datasets like the 419 elements in `$linkedSession`, filtering elements using `Where-Object` can introduce performance bottlenecks. To address this, consider leveraging XPath for optimization, particularly if the structure of the elements allows for it. XPath offers a more efficient approach to filtering based on specific patterns.
3. Optimize looping by utilizing `foreach` over `ForEach-Object` for improved speed. Additionally, leverage PowerShell's parallel processing capabilities, such as jobs or runspaces, to execute independent tasks concurrently, thereby boosting overall performance.

**Powershell code:-**

```
$detailsSession = @"
{
    "Scripts": [
        {"outerHTML": "<script>Script 1</script>"},
        {"outerHTML": "<script>Script 2</script>"},
        {"outerHTML": "<script>Script 3</script>"}
    ]
}
"@

$linkedSession = @"
<elements>
    <element>Record - 1</element>
    <element>Record - 2</element>
    <element>Record - 3</element>
    <element>Other Element</element>
</elements>
"@

# Optimized JSON parsing using ConvertFrom-Json
$unparsedJSON = $detailsSession | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Scripts | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty outerHTML
Write-Host "Unparsed JSON: $unparsedJSON"

# Optimized element filtering using XPath
$linkedRecord = $linkedSession | Select-Xml "//text()[contains(., 'Record -')]" | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerText }
Write-Host "Linked Record: $($linkedRecord -join ', ')"
```

***Output:-***

[image]

You can also start the runbook by using the Powershell command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/start-azautomationrunbook?view=azps-11.3.0#examples) to get more insights on the Run.

```
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "siliconautom" -Name "ps2" -ResourceGroupName "siddheshrg"
```

[image]